# AlchemyNews API multiple relevance scores not working properly

Tags: alchemyapi, alchemy

It doesn’t seem like the relevance score parameters are working when more than 1 used. In other words...I essentially would like to get advertising articles where the concept and keyword is advertising with both relevance scores =>0.8. In addition, use a taxonomy with advertising with a relevance score =>0.8. Here is the query, I separated the parameters to make it easy to read.

```
https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=APIKEY&start=now-7d&end=now&outputMode=json&return=enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title,enriched.url.taxonomy,enriched.url.keywords,enriched.url.concepts
&q.enriched.url.concepts.concept.text=advertising
&q.enriched.url.concepts.concept.relevance=>0.8
&q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_.label=business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising
&q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_.score=>0.8
&q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword.text=advertising
&q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword.relevance=>0.8
&q.enriched.url.title=O-[jobs^job]
&q.enriched.url.title=O-[careers^career]
&q.enriched.url.title=O-[cv^resume]
&dedup=1
&rank=high^medium
```

I am getting article results that has “enriched.url.concepts.concept.text=advertising” with a relevance score lower than “0.8” and/or “enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_.label=business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising” with a relevance score lower than “0.8”. For example, the article “4 Tips for Maximizing the User’s Advertising Experience” in the results is excellent because it meets all 3 of the parameters that require a relevance score (eg has a relevance score >=0.8).

```
"concepts": [
                                    "relevance": 0.974825978,
                                    "text": "Advertising"
                                },
"keywords": [
                                {
                                    "knowledgeGraph": {
                                        "typeHierarchy": "/services/mobile advertising"
                                    },
                                    "relevance": 0.910649002,
                                    "sentiment": {
                                        "mixed": 0,
                                        "score": 0,
                                        "type": "neutral"
                                    },
                                    "text": "mobile advertising"
                                }
"taxonomy": [
                                {
                                    "confident": "",
                                    "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising",
                                    "score": 0.991141975
                                }
```

However, this is an example of what most of the results look like, where it meets none or just one of the relevance scores:

```
"concepts": [{
                                    "relevance": 0.447964013,
                                    "text": "Advertising"
                                }
"keywords": [{
                                    "knowledgeGraph": {
                                        "typeHierarchy": "/people/users/third parties/advertisers"
                                    },
                                    "relevance": 0.623048007,
                                    "sentiment": {
                                        "mixed": 1,
                                        "score": -0.291121989,
                                        "type": "negative"
                                    },
                                    "text": "advertisers"
                                }
"taxonomy": [
                                 {
                                    "confident": "no",
                                    "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising",
                                    "score": 0.345863998
                                }
```

I ultimately would like the query to only return results like the first example where it meets all 3 criteria (e.g. with relevance scores > = 0.8). Could someone please look into this? Is something wrong with the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dennis:
Looks like you encountered a bug in processing of the URL parameters.  The solution requires compactly reformatting your parameters, but that's the preferred format for complicated URLs anyway.

**E.g. instead of sending your parameters like this:**

```
q.enriched.url.concepts.concept.text=Advertising
q.enriched.url.concepts.concept.relevance=>0.80
q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_.score=>0.8
q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_.label=business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising
q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword.text=Advertising
q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword.relevance=>0.80
```

**You would instead group them:**

```
q.enriched.url.concepts.concept=|text=Advertising,relevance=>0.80|
q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_=|score=>0.8,label=business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising|
q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword=|text=Advertising,relevance=>0.80|
```

**So this final URL works for me:**

`https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?q.enriched.url.concepts.concept=|text=Advertising,relevance=>0.80|&q.enriched.url.keywords.keyword=|text=advertising,relevance=>=.8|&q.enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_=|label=business and industrial/advertising and marketing/advertising,score=>=.8|&return=enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title,enriched.url.concepts,enriched.url.taxonomy.taxonomy_,enriched.url.keywords&apikey=APIKEY&start=now-7d&end=now&outputMode=json&q.enriched.url.title=O-[jobs^job]&q.enriched.url.title=O-[careers^career]&q.enriched.url.title=O-[cv^resume]&dedup=1&rank=high^medium`